# Is there any way to add outline to text with destinations, so that it can viewed in getOutline of ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: javascript, pdfmake, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

To display the outlines using **ng2-pdf-viewer** in which the pdf is generated using the **pdfmake** library. Is there any options to put some text as outline text in pdfmake while definnig the document definition?

Answer (score 0):

**Iff we know the titles that need to be outlined**. The solution after all implemented for this functionality is using the Toc (Table of contents)

Define the document defintion like this :

```
generatePDF(): Promise<any>{
  this.documentDefinition = {
    content: [
     {
      tocItem: 'coverpage',
      stack: [
        {
          columns: [
            {
              text: '',
              width: '50%',
              tocItem: true,
            },
            {
              width: '*',
              text: ''
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      pageBreak: 'after',
    },
    {
      text: 'Second toc header',
      tocItem: true,
      pageBreak: 'after',
      bold: true,
    }
   ]
}
// generate 
this.generatedPDF = pdfMake.createPdf(this.documentDefinition)
this.generatedPDF.getBuffer((buffer) => {
    this.pdfSrc = buffer
})
}
```

On after load of the ng2-pdf-viewer use :

```
afterLoadComplete(pdf: PDFDocumentProxy): void {
   this.pdf = pdf
   const toc = this.generatedPDF.docDefinition.content.filter( content => 
   content.toc)
   this.loadOutline(toc)
}

loadOutline(toc: any): void {
  const outlineTitles = [
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
    'item 3',
    'item 4'
  ]
  this.pdf.getDestinations().then((outline: any[]) => {
     this.outline = Object.entries(outline).map( (item, index) => 
     Object.assign(item, {title : outlineTitles[index]}))
  })
}
```

Thus the titles with the destinations will be got.